# C# Linq Select anonymous object into Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, configuration, ienumerable

I've created a custom configuration section that essential holds a collection of key value pairs.  This is all working fine and I can get the elements back.  What I then need to do is then select each element into a dictionary.  I've implemented `IEnumerable<T>` on my `ConfigurationCollectionElement` and again, the variable elements is populated correctly.  However, the code below does not compile.  The error is:

> '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>`' does not
>   contain a definition for '`ToDictionary`'.

This is clearly not true as there are plenty of examples showing this.  What is going on here?

```
{
    var problemDirectory = new Dictionary<string,object>();

    var coreOperands = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("RuntimeCoreOperands") as OperandConfigurationSection;

    var elements = coreOperands.Operands.Select(op => new { Name = op.Name, Symbol = op.Symbol });

    this.problemDirectory = elements.ToDictionary<string, object>(op => op.Name, op => op.Symbol);
}
```

Comment: Have you added `using System.Linq;` ?

Comment: Try to remove `<string, object>`

Comment: @TimSchmelter If `Symbol` isn't an `object`, but the type of the field is a `Dictionary<string,object>` then it wouldn't compile without that.